# Connection Error in python-socketio (exceptions.ConnectionError(exc.args[0]) from None)

Tags: python, socket.io, python-socketio

i write a code and use python-socketio and it works fine.

but sometimes(i mean every 10 or 20 run) i get the error below:

`sio.connect(URL, transports=["websocket"], wait=False)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/socketio/client.py", line 148, in connect  raise exceptions.ConnectionError(exc.args[0]) from None  socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection error`

when i stop and run again it works.

what is the origin of this problem and what should i do?

i only can find the piece of code that error occurs there and that's it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry i can not share code its for my company that i'm worked for and i'm not allowed. but shortly i'm emitting on some channels and listen to them in an event. and i don't use namespaces

Comment: This is a connection error. Try looking at the logs from the server to see why the connection was rejected.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg. thank you so much. if it is from server it is OK for me. thank you for your useful package:))